# Rails3: How to execute Rails commands (like "rails generate") with shell script

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, shell, generator

I need to be able to generate a model (and later a migration) by executing a Linux shell script.

The script is located directly in the app folder and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/<my_user_profile>/Websites/<my_app_name>
rails g model my_model name:string accepted:boolean [etc...]
```

The problem is: When I execute the script, the model does not get created. Any ideas why?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a Rails generator?

Comment: @coreyward: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I definitely will check that out (but still curious about my issue...).

Comment: @Dave Newton: Nothing happens, the console gets ready for another command, as if the first command was executed successfully...

Comment: @TomDogg Are you using rvm or anything? W/o the shebang it works fine for me when executing from a shell that's already using the correct rvm/gemset--don't see any reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: @Dave Newton: Thanks Dave, that did it! I thought the #!/bin/bash
was mandatory for every .sh script... Also, the "cd" turns out to be unnecessary since the .sh file is already in the app root folder. No, I'm not using RVM or anything. Don't forget to add your answer below if you want the karma ;-)

Comment: @TomDogg Done; glad you got it working. But unless it takes cmd line args, what good is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure it's executing in the same context your shell is in, remove the shebang to avoid starting up another `bash` which may or may not be the same as your current shell.

If you're using rvm/similar, you'd need to either (a) have a default, (b) specify version/gemset, or (c) rely on rvm-like `cd` fudgery.

Otherwise, should work just fine--it is for me (w/o the shebang, so it'll use whatever current rvm environment I'm in).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
exec "rails g model my_model name:string accepted:boolean"
```